# PHP5.5 Opcache per folder caching

Tags: php, opcache

I switched one webserver to PHP 5.5 and by default it comes with Zend Opcache. Found it very straigthforwaded for configuration as APC was. The problem in Opcache that i need somehow define to cache only files in specific folder. 
Found in php.net

> opcache.blacklist_filename string
>
> ```
> The location of the OPcache blacklist file. A blacklist file is a text file containing the names of files that should not be
> ```
>
> accelerated, one per line. Wildcards are allowed, and prefixes can
>   also be provided. Lines starting with a semi-colon are ignored as
>   comments.
>
> ```
> A simple blacklist file might look as follows:
>
> ; Matches a specific file.
> /var/www/broken.php
> ; A prefix that matches all files starting with x.
> /var/www/x
> ; A wildcard match.
> /var/www/*-broken.php
> ```

But I have 150 folders e.g. websites and how may i just define to cache only particular folders ?
As for my view now i assume that I may prevent caching by putting list of unwanted folder in blacklist file:

```
/var/www/domain.com/*
/var/www/domain.net/*
/var/www/domain.org/*
```

Comment: The idea of "Ask question" is that you ask a question.

Comment: @TerryE Question is already there "how may i just define to cache only particular folders ?"  What's wrong with it ? And i wrote my research how to do that, but looking for alternative if it exists. It was nice to do in APC in that way apc.filters="+domain.com,-domain.org"  So if "-" folder won't be cached, and sure apc.cache_by_default = 0  have to be defined to prevent caching all.

Comment: You can't easily, with the blacklist functionality as currently implemented.  It's not a regexp, only a set of simple wildcards which is compiled into one compound regexp, so can use negative assertions, nor can you easily limit caching to specific folders.  Sorry. See `ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_blacklist.c` in the php-src in gihub for more details.  //Terry